# How to create DataFrame out of SparkSession object to read PNG file format?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I am using Spark2.0.0 in my dev environment. I have created SparkSession object as below

```
spark = SparkSession().getOrCreate()
Image = spark.read.json()
```

I can use the above SparkSession to read the json files. But is there a way to read image file(PNG, JPG)? I have tried searching the spark 2.0 document, but nothing has been mentioned about it.

My main goal is to load the images as DF from some localFileSyatem/HDFS location through

```
Image = spark.read.()
```

and save them as a sequential file in HDFS location for image processing.

How can we accomplish this task? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WholeTextFile() method provided by SparkContext. I am not much used to code in python. But, I can help you with JAVA example.

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext();
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("image-path", 1).toJavaRDD();
rdd.foreach(x -> {

});
```

Once, you get hold of the data you can use your own video/image library to process the image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but we do not use Java in our environement

Comment: What ever language it is an RDD is same across all the languages. The logic is same.

Answer (score 0):

It was a hit and trial method. Instead of using sparkSession I have used SparkContext and used its in-built feature.

```
image = sc.textFile("hdfs:/<path_to/image2.png",1)
```

The Spark read it without any error. 
Hope this will come handy to others as well.